# Cobol - CICS DB2 - commits only last insert

Tags: db2, ibm-mq, cobol, cics

There are two pgms

1. COBOL CICS (Main PGM) which reads mq queue, triggers transaction and send response back.
2. Cobol CICS DB2 (Sub PGM) which logs mq details to DB2 table which made in main PGM.

The problem is when at the end of uow, only last inserted data into table(From Sub pgm) were committed but not previously inserted from previous calls.

I tested with explicit commit also but results are same. But if we give syncpoint in PGM 2 which works but eventually collapses other updates done to vsam files from another sub pgms.

Main Pgm (Read MQ, Write MQ) -> Sub Pgm( Logs MQ details (Q/R) to DB2 table) returns control back once inserted.

Any help?

Comment: How is the subprogram being invoked?  Are you using CALL 'program' or EXEC CICS LINK?  Is more than one CICS region involved?

Comment: It's being invoked using 'EXEC CICS LINK'
Both pgms runs under same region

Comment: You say "at the end of uow". Could you please update your question to help us understand the scope of your UoW. How many messages and DB2 updates are in your UoW (your problem description suggests >1). How are you committing said UoW? Are the messages which drove the missing DB2 inserts still on the queue, or gone.

Answer (score 1):

OK -- with EXEC CICS LINK and both programs executing in the same CICS region, then the task automatically has transactionality across all resource managers, MQ as well as Db2. Your program can interfere with this by explicitly issuing the EXEC CICS SYNCPOINT command or the EXEC SQL COMMIT command.

I'm not sure I'm clear on what you mean when you say "triggers the transaction" as an action in your main program.  By "transaction" do you mean a unit of work/recovery or do you mean a new CICS task?  How is this triggering accomplished?

If your flow is simply:

- MQ message arrives
- Main program begins execution (triggered by MQ message)
- Main program retrieves item from queue
- Main program LINKs to subprogram
- Subprogram issues INSERT to Db2 table
- Subprogram returns to main program
- Main program sends MQ reply
- Main program retrieves next message from queue
- Main program LINKs to subprogram
- Subprogram issues INSERT to Db2 table
- Subprogram returns to main program
- Main program sends MQ reply
- -- maybe repeat the GET, LINK, INSERT, RETURN, PUT sequence a couple of times
- Main program returns/terminates normally

At this point the Db2 table should have multiple inserted rows.

You could optionally issue a SYNCPOINT/COMMIT after each MQ PUT command to cause the reply to flow immediately and commit the update to the Db2 table. (The original input MQ message is also permanently removed from the queue manager.)

If you are still having a problem with these programs, try asking a colleague to review them to see where you might have introduced an error.

If you think that CICS and/or Db2 are failing, you can open a case to IBM Support to get more assistance.